# How to fix RuntimeError & Segmentation fault while running demo codes in auto-07p

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, fortran, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I was running demo codes in AUTO-07p, which is mainly based on fortran but also following python syntax, but I was getting same error when I run most of demo codes. Since they're not written by me, but written by experts and has been released for a long time, so there must NOT an error. Maybe I don't have to modify the codes.

So when I run codes containing either bifurcation analysis part or plotting, I kept getting an error message RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object. 
So, I tried to change recursion limit to 10^7, but then I got the error message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```py
    demo('bvp')

    bvp =run('bvp')
    branchpoints = bvp("BP")
    for solution in branchpoints: 
        bp = load(solution,ISW=-1,NTST=50)
        # Compute forwards
        print "Solution label",bp["LAB"],"forwards"
        fw = run(bp)
        # Compute backwards 
        print "Solution lavel", bp["LAB"], "backwards"
        bw = run(bp,DS='-')
        both = fw + bw
        merged = merge(both) 
        bvp = bvp + merged 

    bvp=relavel(bvp) 
    save(bvp, 'bvp')
    plot(bvp)
    wait()
```

The error message says (excluding seemingly unnecessary lines)

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in flatnonzero(a)
>
> 924
>      925
>   -->926 return np.nonzero(np.ravel(a))[0]
>      927
>      928
>   ... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in flatnonzero(a)
>
> 924
>      925
>   -->926 return np.nonzero(np.ravel(a))[0]
>      927
>      928
>
> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python   object

So it seems the code is stuck in an infinite loop, but that flatnonzero function is simply indexing nonzero entries... I'm not sure what should I do